# Gradle + Java, multiproject build.gradle

Tags: java, spring, gradle, manifest

This is my file hierarchy, 'Domain Module' has no code right now, basically a wrapper for DBController and Domain.

```
Domain Module
  .gradle
  .idea
  build
  DBController
      build
      src
          main
              java
                  interfaces
                      IDBController.java
                  DBController.java
          res
              some SQL files
          test
              java
                  some test files
      build.gradle

  Domain
      .gradle
      build
      gradle
      src
          main
              java
                  Server.java
      build.gradle
      gradlew
      gradlew.bat
      settings.gradle
  gradle
  build.gradle
  gradlew
  gradlew.bat
  settings.gradle
```

This is my build.gradle in Domain Module/build.gradle

```
group 'Group'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT' 

apply plugin: 'java'
targetCompatibility = 1.8
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':Domain')
    compile project(':DBController')
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
}
```

this is build.gradle in DOmain Module/DBController/build.gradle

```
group 'Group'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'
  compileJava {
      sourceCompatibility = 1.8
      targetCompatibility = 1.8
  }

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.postgresql:postgresql:9.3-1103-jdbc3'
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
}

dependencies {
    compile('com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1.1')
    compile files('libs/json-simple-1.1.1.jar')
    compile('org.postgresql:postgresql:9.3-1103-jdbc3')
}
```

And finally, build.gradle in Domain Module/Domain/build.gradle

```
group 'Group'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

sourceCompatibility = 8
targetCompatibility = 8

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.3'
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':DBController')
}
```

My main method is in Server.java, and it uses an instance of DBController. How do i assign this file in my java manifest? I've tried the simple

```
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'Domain.src.main.java.Server'

}
```

but whenever i try to execute java -jar -the generated jar in Domain Module/build/libs-
i get an error telling me it can't find the main file, and as the build gradles are now it gives me an error saying there's no reference to a main class at all.

The gist of my project is that DBController issues queries against a SQL server, and that Server.java will be a spring server. I decided to use gradle to do this so i would learn, and while i have learned alot about gradle, there is still much uncertainty.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out what was wrong.

```
jar {
  manifest {
    attributes 'Main-Class': '-insert main class here-'
  }
}
```

This attribute assumes you're in the src/main/java dir to begin with, so if my filepath was

```
src/main/java/robert/util/Class.java
```

i would just have to say

```
jar {
  manifest {
    attributes 'Main-Class': 'robert.util.Class'
  }
}
```

Spent so much time solving such a trivial error. My tip for anyone else is to not overlook the 'intro to gradle' sites and such. The solution was there all along.